# Cannot insert sqlite using select option in cordova

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

I made ​​a simple application with apache cordova , I try to save data into sqlite  using select option but errors, cannot be save to sqlite and using jquery mobile.

This my script

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name book" />
  <select name="year">
        <option  value="0">Year Publish</option>
        <option  value="2011">2011</option>
        <option  value="2012">2012</option>
        <option  value="2013">2013</option>
        <option  value="2014">2014</option>
        <option  value="2015">2015</option>
        <option  value="2016">2016</option>
  </select>
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function insertDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO BUKU (name,jilid) VALUES ("' +document.getElementById("name").value
                        +'","'+document.getElementById("jilid").value+'")');
        }

    function goInsert() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Buku", 200000);
            db.transaction(insertDB, errorCB, successCB);
        }
function populateDB(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BUKU (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name,jilid)');
   }

function errorCB(err) {
       alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
   }

function successCB() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Buku", 200000);
            db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
   }

function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Buku", 200000);
            db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
   }
```

Comment: Are you using the browser sqlite or the cordova plugin? Are the tables well created? Is the database opened? Post more info. Also the select is not referenced anywhere in the JS

Comment: thanks @Del, yes I use cordova-plugin-sqlite , and displays it on the table adn open database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe the problem are the data types, try creating the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BUKU (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT,jilid TEXT)
```

Also the execute function should be like this to prevent injection, and problems with quotes

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO BUKU (name,jilid) VALUES (?,?)', [document.getElementById("name").value, document.getElementById("jilid").value]);
```